# Check if any element of a list is in a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, matrix

I have a small list:

```
list2 = ['hi', 'ma', 'ja']
```

and I have a matrix too. for example:

```
matrix2 = ([['high','h ight','hi ght','h i g ht'],
       ['man','ma n','ma th','mat h'],
       ['ja cket','j a ck et','jack et','ja m']
       ['ma nkind','jack',' hi ','hi'])
```

And I need to determine if any of the elements of l ist2 of this array are not in the matrix2.
I try to use np.isin() :

```
np.isin(matrix2,list2)
```

But this code only shows if there is the elements in the matrix or not completely. But I need this output:

```
output = ([[False, False, True, False],
       [False, True, True, False],
       [True, False, False, True]
       [True, False, True, False])])
```

As you can see in the output, the spaces are important too. For example, 'hi' without space before and after it is not something that I want it. I need the list by considering spaces between the set of characters.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: with what logic you get  `output[0][4] = [True, False, True, False]`

Comment: @user1740577 Seems to be an error. Should be `[True, False, True, True]`.

Comment: Spaces. 'hi' without space before and after it is not something that I want it. I need the list by considering spaces between the set of characters. @user1740577

Comment: @exocytosis Then you might want to add this limitation to the question. Wouldn't it be enough to define `list2 = ['hi ',' hi',  'ma', 'ja']`

Comment: You are right. I'll do it now. @Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the matrix and then over each row of the matrix. Then you have a single string that you have to split to get the individual parts. Now you can check if any of this parts is in `list2`.

list2 = ['hi', 'ma', 'ja']

```
matrix2 = [['high','h ight','hi ght','h i g ht'],
            ['man','ma n','ma th','mat h'],
            ['ja cket','j a ck et','jack et','ja m'],
            ['ma nkind','jack',' hi ','hi']]

output = []
for row in matrix2:
    new_row = [any(value in list2 for value in element.split()) for element in row]
    output.append(new_row)
print(output)
```

The result is

```
[[False, False, True, False], 
 [False, True, True, False], 
 [True, False, False, True], 
 [True, False, True, True]]
```

---

A minor change that takes the additional constraint of an existing space into account.

```
output = []
for row in matrix2:
    new_row = [any(value in list2 and ' ' in element for value in element.split()) for element in row]
    output.append(new_row)
print(output)
```

This will give you

```
[[False, False, True, False],
 [False, True, True, False],
 [True, False, False, True],
 [True, False, True, False]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately I cant run this code.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "I can't run this code"? Do you get an error or do you refer to the additional constraint you gave in the comments after I answered?

Comment: I wanted to delete my comment. I had a problem with my compiler so I had an error. After refreshing compiler, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: OK. In that case I have an alternative version for you. You might want to try that.